# Sending Video to iPhone user

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mms, att

What is the best way to send a video that is over the MMS allowed size to an iPhone user?  I really don't see any good way to do it besides uploading to some sort of 3rd party (youtube, gdrive, etc..) and then sharing it to them?  Even using non-mms with hangouts doesn't seem to allow me to send video that I have previously taken.

Any suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: Email would be my first thought, followed immediately by cloud storage (well before thinking about MMS, don't even want to think what sending an MMS video costs)

Comment: @GAThrawn I get unlimited text and media stuff with my contract, but it is still depressing.  iMessage would let you send anything pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I have used [Sizable Send](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.sizablesend.android) to transfer very large videos from my phone to my boss's. You can send them the download link via email or text.

Alternatively, if the video isn't very large you could use [Dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) in the same way

Depending on the file size it might take a while to transfer.

Answer (score -2):

Email, or if not cloud storage or Instagram direct messaging. If you're close you could also do Bluetooth.